# I want to convert int to char array where 0-7 bits of int are 1st char 8-15 2nd etc

Tags: c++

So here is the code but for some reason intToChar function returns "abcd" and some gibberish at the end. I was trying to change my newly created array to 0 first but then I'm getting access violation errors.

```
int charToInt(char x[])
{
    int z = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(int) / sizeof(char) && x[i]; i++)
    {
        z <<= sizeof(char) * 8;
        z |= x[i];
    }
    return z;
}
char* intToChar(int x)
{
    char* z = new char[5];
    for (int i = (sizeof(z) / sizeof(z[0]) - 1); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        z[i] = x;
        x >>= sizeof(char) * 8;
    }
    return z;
}

int main()
{
    char xd[5] = "abcd";
    cout << xd;
    cout << endl;
    int x = charToInt(xd);
    cout << x;
    cout << endl;
    char* y = intToChar(x);
    cout << y;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(z) / sizeof(z[0]) ` -- `z` is a POINTER so `sizeof(z)` is `sizeof (A_POINTER)`... `sizeof (char)` is defined as `1` and so should be omitted from multiplication.

Comment: Also, in addition to the broken sizeof logic: `&& x[i]` -- can you please [explain to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) what this is supposed to do?

Comment: I was now talking half the night to my rubber duck, and after instensive discussions, with many ups and downs, we came to the first initial idea that maybe ````&& x[i]```` could possibly have the intention to not read past the end of the string. But I planned some further sessions with my rubber duck for further clarifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, your use of `sizeof(z)` is `sizeof(a_pointer)` -- not what you want. Instead, given that `sizeof(char)` is always `1`, you can simply do:

```
#include <iostream>

int charToInt (char *x)
{
    int z = 0;
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(int) && x[i]; i++)
    {
        z <<= 8;
        z |= x[i];
    }
    
    return z;
}

char *intToChar (int x)
{
    char *z = new char[5];
    
    for (int i = (int)sizeof (int) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        z[i] = x;
        x >>= 8;
    }
    
    return z;
}

int main()
{
    char xd[5] = "abcd";
    std::cout << xd << '\n';
    
    int x = charToInt (xd);
    std::cout << x << '\n';
    
    char *y = intToChar(x);
    std::cout << y << '\n';
}
```

(**note:** the loop limits have been adjusted to reflect that fact you are utilizing only 4-bytes in your conversion either way)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/chr2int2char
abcd
1633837924
abcd
```

Alternatively, you can write `intToChar()` as follows:

```
char *intToChar (int x)
{
    char *z = new char[5];
    int i  = sizeof (int);
    z[i] = 0;               /* affirmatively nul-terminate z */
    
    while (i--)
    {
        z[i] = x;
        x >>= 8;
    }
    
    return z;
}
```

Also, if you were calling from a function other than `main()`, you would want to ensure you `delete[] y;` to avoid a memory leak, e.g.

```
    char *y = intToChar(x);
    std::cout << y << '\n';
    
    delete[] y;
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

You have couple of problems in the code you have write:

1. You do: `"(sizeof(z) / sizeof(z[0]) - 1)"` but size of 'z' is the size of pointer which is 8 bytes in most PCs today.
2. You haven't set the null terminator in the string, in the last byte of the char*

z[4] = '\0';

3. You forgot to delete the dynamic allocation of the char*, you should delete it in the main function after printing it.

If you will fix all of that, it will work as expected, but here you have a simple code to perform what you meant:

```
int charToInt(char x[])
{
    int z = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
      z <<=  8;        
      z |= x[i];
    }
    return z;
}


char* intToChar(int x)
{  
  char* z = new char[5];
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    z[i] = x >> (4 - i - 1) * 8;
  }
  z[4] = '\0';
  
  return z; 
}


int main()
{
  char xd[5] = "abcd";
  cout << xd << endl;
  
  int x = charToInt(xd);
  cout << x <<endl;
  
  char* y = intToChar(x);
  cout << y << endl;
  delete[] y;
  return 0;
}
```